# sre_constants.error: missing ),unterminated subpattern

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

i am gaurav and i am learning programming. i was reading regular expressions in dive into python 3,so i thought to try myself something so i wrote this code in eclipse but i got a lot of errors.can anyone pls help me

```
import re
def add_shtner(add):
    return re.sub(r"\bROAD\b","RD",add)
print(add_shtner("100,BROAD ROAD"))


# a code to check valid roman no.
ptn=r"^(M{0,3})(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3}$)"
def romancheck(num):
    num=num.upper()
    if re.search(ptn,num):
        return "VALID"
    else:
        return "INVALID"
print(romancheck("MMMLXXVIII"))
print(romancheck("MMMLxvviii"))

mul_line_str='''adding third argument
             re.VERBOSE in re.search()     
                   will ignore whitespace
                               and comments'''

print(re.search("re.search()will",mul_line_str,re.VERBOSE))
print(re.search("re.search() will",mul_line_str,re.VERBOSE))
print(re.search("ignore",mul_line_str,re.VERBOSE))

ptn='''
     ^                        #beginning of the string
     M{0,3}                   #thousands-0 to 3 M's
     (CM|CD|D?C{0,3}          #hundreds
     (XC|XL|L?XXX)            #tens
     (IX|IV|V?III)            #ones 
     $                        #end of the string
     '''
print(re.search(ptn,"MMMCDLXXIX",re.VERBOSE))
def romanCheck(num):
    num=num.upper()
    if re.search(ptn,num,re.VERBOSE):
        return "VALID"
    else:
        return "INVALID"

print(romanCheck("mmCLXXXIV"))
print(romanCheck("MMMCCLXXXiv"))
```

i wrote this code and i ran it but i got this-

```
100,BROAD RD
VALID
INVALID
None
None
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(120, 126), match='ignore'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\pydev\xyz\rts\regular_expressions.py", line 46, in <module>
    print(re.search(ptn,"MMMCDLXXIX",re.VERBOSE))
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\re.py", line 182, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\re.py", line 301, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\sre_compile.py", line 562, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\sre_parse.py", line 856, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, 0)
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\sre_parse.py", line 416, in _parse_sub
    not nested and not items))
  File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\sre_parse.py", line 768, in _parse
    source.tell() - start)
sre_constants.error: missing ), unterminated subpattern at position 113 (line 4, column 6)
```

what are these errors can anyone help me.
i have understood all the output but i am not able to understand this errors

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you have passed a malformed regular expression to the `search()` function in line 46.

Although you have defined a valid RegEx in this line:

```
ptn=r"^(M{0,3})(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3}$)"
```

you overwrite this pattern (ptn) later with what seems to be some help/docstring:

```
ptn='''
     ^                        #beginning of the string
     M{0,3}                   #thousands-0 to 3 M's
     (CM|CD|D?C{0,3}          #hundreds
     (XC|XL|L?XXX)            #tens
     (IX|IV|V?III)            #ones 
     $                        #end of the string
     '''
```

This is not a valid RegEx pattern, it is missing a closing bracket after `(CM|CD|D?C{0,3}`.
You pass this new string as regular expression in the nex line `print(re.search(ptn,"MMMCDLXXIX",re.VERBOSE))` and `re.compile()` throws that error.

If you use another name for the variable to hold your help/docstring in line 27 (based on your sample code or line 38 based on your stacktrace) everything looks fine:

```
100,BROAD RD
VALID
INVALID
None
None
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(85, 91), match='ignore'>
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 10), match='MMMCDLXXIX'>
VALID
VALID
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue when using `re.VERBOSE`. I suggest not using it in that format. Create the pattern in a single line rather than over multiple lines and don't pass the verbose parameter.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29817774)